# Crash with Android 4.1 with ArrayMap

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, array-map

I get an error in my code with this logcat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.ArrayMap
at it.dd.multiplayerit.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:88)
at it.dd.multiplayerit.SwipeMainFragment$SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(SwipeMainFragment.java:200)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:456)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:665)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:447)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:861)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2367)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4236)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that the problem is the autocompletetextview i created. I mapped the array to get the position of array when i click in the dropdown during type what i want search.

At line 88 i have this:

```
ArrayMap<String, Integer>myArrayMap = new ArrayMap<String, Integer>();
```

The crash seems to be only with android 4.1 version. Is there any incompatibility?

Answer (score 30):

`ArrayMap` was introduced in Api level 19, but it was also released in the compatibility library v4, so it would be enough to change the import to `android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap` instead of `android.util.ArrayMap`

Comment: @End.Game shouldn't this be accepted as a correct answer?

Comment: @Blackbelt i am getting this error :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzd.<clinit>(Unknown Source) then how can i import android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap and where should i do this

Comment: @pks which version of the support library -v4 are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

For now it migrates to AndroidX.
Instead of `android.util.ArrayMap` you will write `androidx.collection.ArrayMap`