# ArrayMap api level 16

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an application for a device that's running android 4.1.1 ( api 16 ) but I designed the app for api 19. Everything went fine until I installed it on an api 16 device.. and I know why!

ArrayMap isn't available on api 16, any idea what could be a good replacement for it? I'm saving a key -> value pair in the ArrayMap and actually want to keep it this way.

Note: I'm not allowed to give away pieces of the code.

---

I found the solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574323/crash-with-android-4-1-with-arraymap). All I had to do was change the include to:

```
android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
```

Comment: Can someone tag Android-4.1.1 as a keyword? I don't have the required reputation to create a new tag.

Comment: Oh, resolved. I'll add an edit for the people who are having the same problem